# What assumptions can be made in the proof by contradiction of $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I am new to proof-writing and trying to make sense of what constraints are there when making assumptions when proving by contradiction.

When setting up the proof by contradiction, we assumed three things:

1) $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

2) there exist natural numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $\sqrt{2} = \frac{p}{q}$.

3) both $p$ and $q$ have no common factors.

We then go on to show that both $p$ and $q$ are even, contradicting the assumption that $p$ and $q$ have no common factors. There is nothing in the definition of rational numbers that requires p/q to be in irreducible form. So why do we make assumption 3) in the first place?

Any clarification is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only assumption is (1) $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. Since any rational number can be written as $\frac{p}{q}$, for some $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$, (2) is a consequence of (1). Without loss of generality, we can pick $p,q$ such that they don't have a common divisor. Suppose their greatest common divisor is $d \in \mathbb{N}$ with $d \neq 1$. Then, we can write $\sqrt{2} = \frac{\frac{p}{d}}{\frac{q}{d}}$ to get two natural numbers $\frac{p}{d}, \frac{q}{d}$ that satisfy (3). So, our only assumption towards the contradiction is (1), which is what we find to be false at the end of the proof.

Comment: I suppose you mean $d$ is the *greatest* common divisor

Comment: Yes, let me clarify that in the text. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It helped clarify things a lot but not completely. Ok so we only assume 1), and consequently 2). At this point, p/q could be reducible or irreducible. If irreducible we get the contradiction. On the other hand, if in the reducible form, how do p and q being even cause the contradiction?

Comment: If no irreducible $p,q$ exists, then no $p,q$ exists whose ratio is $\sqrt{2}$. If there was a pair that was reducible, then there would have been a corresponding irreducible pair, as well, due to the procedure I described above. If no such $p,q$ exist, by definition of rationals, $\sqrt{2}$ can not be a rational number. More succinctly, ($\not \exists$ irreducible $p,q$ such that $\sqrt{2} = p/q$) $\implies$ ($\not \exists p,q$ such that $\sqrt{2} = p/q$)

Comment: Rational numbers have the property that they can always be written in the form p/q where p and q have no common factors other than +/- 1. Now onto the contradiction. Our proof shows that p and q are even, and thus not simplified as far as possible. Furthermore, there is no way to get an irreducible pair p and q, because, [since p and q were chosen arbitrarily] for any choice of p and q, they are always even. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. To be fully explicit, I would conclude with "Therefore, no irreducible pair $p,q$ exists and $\sqrt{2}$ can not be a rational number".

Comment: Got it. Thank you.